# Tab-completion in iPython on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: python, readline, ipython, tab-completion

I have installed iPython and Readline on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and am having difficulty getting tab-completion to work properly.

For example, when I do

```
import sys
sys.<tab>
```

the tab key only registers as a normal tab.  However, when I do

```
import sys
sys.<alt+tab>
```

it works as it should, returning all possible completions.

I would appreciate any tips to get this working properly.  I know it seems trivial, but "alt+tab" is a pain compared to "tab".

I am using these versions of iPython and Readline:

readline-6.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by using the new stable release of iPython (0.11). According to the iPython website this release is "a major new version and the result of over two years of work."

An iPython egg based on Python 2.6 can be found [here](http://ipython.org/download.html).